# How to take input from a file in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

While debugging from console in Google Chrome, I'd like to take my testcases from a text file uploaded at a url, say **mysite.com/testcases.txt**. How can I do that?

Comment: do you mean load them? use an ajax call on the console with the url pointing to that url.

Comment: I mean I simply want to access them, to be put in a for loop and tested against errors

Comment: then just type out an ajax call in the javascript console then execute it like you would with a regular javascript file.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Okay, one thing. My page loads every time I try a test case and my for loop is destroyed. What to do to continuously check?

Comment: $(function () {
            $.get(
            "file.txt",
            function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
        });

Comment: You might be better off using a tool like Selenium. But if you really want to do it this way, you probably need to run the test cases in a separate window than where you loop through the list (so that the for-loop isn't destroyed). It would help to have some general idea of what sort of test cases are in the testcase.txt file (like comma-separated input for a form? or what?)

Comment: It's space separated.

Comment: ....You know it's really frustrating when you take the effort to answer a question (even a bad one, like [your DLL question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341820/how-to-encrypt-text-via-dll)), just to have the OP delete it. I'll keep that in mind before answering next time.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm really sorry. I don't like to delete questions, but I guess it was out of scope of this site.